# Remotely control Canon EOS 60D from Android phone through MacBook

Tags: canon, wireless, eos-utility, stop-motion, android-app

I have a Canon EOS 60D DSLR and I want to shoot with it a stop motion animation.

From my first try I learned that I shouldn't touch the camera at all.
I can control the camera remotely with EOS Utility 2 software when the camera is connected by USB to my MacBook.

It's a great easy-to-use software! But I have to come to my MacBook each time I want to press the shutter button. I would prefer to do it remotely from my Android phone.

Since the camera doesn't have Bluetooth/WiFi module, the only way to connect it to the phone wirelessly - to do it through MacBook.
It seems that EOS Utility 2 and Canon Camera Connect application cannot connect to each other (at least I didn't find a way to do it).

Is there any software that can control the camera through the chain `Android phone -> MacBook -> Canon EOS DSLR`.

Since I'm not a professional I'm looking for ***FREE/very cheap*** option (otherwise I would by Dragonframe 4 with Bluetooth Controller).

**Update:**
The issue was solved with wireless mouse. Wireless keyboard should also work.

Comment: So, what's wrong with either a cabled shutter release or remote shutter release again? These devices have existed for decades in some shape or form and are plenty cheap to obtain...

Comment: Is there a reason other than the trigger the shutter that you want to have the camera connected to the Mac? Are you shooting tethered and want to see previews? Or do you only want the Mac in the loop because you think it is the only way to trigger the shutter remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the two devices in the same network you can easily use a remote software which can be used to control the whole PC. like for example [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com), [Splashtop](https://www.splashtop.com) or any other remote desktop software with an app. Then you can control your MAC with the phone and trigger the camera with the Canon application on the MAC.
Another very easy possibility to solve this is to use a wireless keyboard mouse combo like the Logitech K400.

But I am sorry I am not aware of an app which could directly solve your problem..

Comment: thank you for your answer! Actually after posting the question I realised that my wireless mouse is good enough for this purpose :) Of course any specialised software would be better, but if it doesn't exist or no-one is aware about it, I will mark you answer as accepted

Comment: If you want to do this more often you can also buy a remote trigger for your camera. The cable releases are costing just around 15€ and the wireless are also not that expensive ( if you are not using the first party ones like the canon or nikon, these are just expensive and cannot do more than the cheap ones)

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an answer to your question, but then your question seems to be an X→Y question. It seems what you really want is just a way to trigger the shutter on the camera wirelessly?

For that, the simplest solution with the fewest limitations would be a wireless radio release with a receiver that plugs into your camera's wired cable release port.

[image]
<sub>This one is currently [$21 at amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JVC5PP6)</sub>

You can also get them without a built-in intervalometer but they're not much, if any, cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a USB Keyboard or mouse to be able to press the button on the MAC from across the room.  Not exactly what you wanted, but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Get a [Canon RC-6 IR remote](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/683524-REG/Canon_4524B001_RC_6_Wireless_Remote_Control.html). They cost less then $25, or you can buy a [knockoff](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BCEJ0E0) for much less.

It's only good for line of sight and about 15', but that should work for your situation.

Comment: Are you sure the 60D has an IR receiver? My 50D does not.

Comment: @MichaelC - yes, it does. The RC-6 lists it as a compatible camera.

Answer (score 0):

Beside listed in other answers you can use few more ways to activate your camera remotely:

1. Using USB OTG adapter for your phone and software like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.qdd)
2. Using TP-Link N150 with [custom firmware](https://dslrdashboard.info/downloads/) and the same software as above for the phone

You can check [this website](https://dslrdashboard.info/) for some ideas, manuals and software

P.S. No affiliation with the websites and products